# High level online protocol

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

I am trying to develop my own online game for training purpose.
I have some questions, and I can't find any answers that satisfy me.

1. Does it exist an online protocol to exchange data between two players? I don't mean TCP or UDP, but a high level protocol. I am looking for a WebService or Remoting with events. I use for now [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html), but I need more flexibility (like events). I can develop my own protocol, but I think it exists already a network protocol with events.
2. I will use the "Command" design pattern or Flex/Bison to parse the query. Is there a better way ?

**EDIT**
For protocol, I use "protocol buffers".
So I have two options :

- Translate my custom protocol into events and callback.
- Use a protocol/tool that have already events. Is there such a tool ?

Thank you for your responses.
Regards

Romain

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing protocol with protocol implementation. A protocol defines what the messages you send mean and how they are serialized. A message can generate an event at a client  but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Indeed, I mixed theses two notions. I'll clarify them in my post.